# How to disable unauthenticated binds in Active Directory(2016)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

How to disable unauthenticated binds in Active Directory(2016). I followed up this approach: 
https://lithnet.io/blog/2018/12/disabling-unauthenticated-binds-in
https://lithnet.io/blog/2017/01/ad-lds-and-ldap-unauthenticated-binds

But still I was able to authenticate without providing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The [same link](https://lithnet.io/blog/2018/12/disabling-unauthenticated-binds-in) also states in the end:

> "Granted, it's not a perfect outcome - you still need to upgrade all
>   your domain controllers and/or LDS servers to Windows Server 2019 to
>   take advantage of this capability, but if this is Important to you,
>   there is at least a solution available".

Please upgrade your server to Windows Server 2019, as it doesn't work on Server 2016!